# I am not getting json response on my console

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am working on project where I am currently trying to get a json response displayed on my console and it is not working. Instead of getting the json object, I am getting weird looking javascript program on the console.
Here is my code:

```
var settings = {
    header:{
      Accept: "application/json "
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      console.log(data)
    } 

  }

  jQuery.ajax(settings, url);
```

Here is the [Documentaion](https://skyscanner.github.io/slate/#flights-browse-prices)

Here is the some part of the console display I am getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html data-brackets-id="1"><head data-brackets-id="2" data-bramble-start-line="2" data-bramble-start-ch="0" data-bramble-end-line="7" data-bramble-end-ch="7"><base href="https://mozillathimblelivepreview.net/bramble/production/dist/index.html?locale=en-US">
<script>
(function(global){"use strict";var parent=window.opener||window.parent;var postMessageTransport={_callbacks:null,setCallbacks:function(callbacks){this._callbacks=callbacks},connect:function(url){var self=this;parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({type:"connect",url:global.location.href}),"*");if(self._callbacks&&self._callbacks.connect){self._callbacks.connect()}},send:function(msgStr){parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({type:"message",message:msgStr}),"*")},enable:function(){this.connect();var self=this;window.addEventListener("message",function(event){if(self._callbacks&&self._callbacks.message){self._callbacks.message(event.data)}})}};global._Brackets_LiveDev_Transport=postMessageTransport})(this);</script>
<script>
(function(global){"use strict";var transport=global._Brackets_LiveDev_Transport;var XMLHttpRequest=global.XMLHttpRequest;if(!XMLHttpRequest){console.error("[Brackets LiveDev] XMLHttpRequest not
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing?

Comment: Please post the result of the `console.log()` here.

Comment: I suspect the issue arises from header object. However, I am certain

Comment: Reverse the order of the parameters `jQuery.ajax(url, settings)` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Jasen That still would't account for why the `console.log()` would even fire off since the `success` handler wouldn't be reached.

Comment: I tried to reverse the order of the parameters and I am getting this error GET ......url....... net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: Are you attempting to call for a resource that originates from a different domain than the calling page?

Comment: @Scott ofcourse, I dont know if you have seen the documentation yet but if I owned the api which provides the resource, I wouldnt have been stuck on this issue ... lol

Comment: This example dumps my view in success http://plnkr.co/edit/ueYvq38QLuSTHTflMAFN?p=preview

Comment: What do you think about how the header object is set up?

Comment: It may not make a difference, but you have a trailing space in: `"application/json "`. Also, the documentation talks about authentication with a key. Is that set up correctly?

Comment: @Scott ya. I have made a post request using postman, the response is properly working given all the necessary authentication.